# How to have different code on two branches same repo | GIT + Android Studio

Tags: android, git

I'm new to Git and although I understand the basics of it, there's a thing that I can't understand or maybe it doesn't work the way I want to.
The issue is like this:

1. I purchased an Android app (source code let's call it ver.2) from codecanyon and I've done the re-skin of it, changing the package name and changes on code on some of the files and uploaded the file on Google Play Store.
2. Now the dev has uploaded a new version (update) of the source code (ver.3) on codecanyon and it says that "A complete reinstallation project is required" in order to update my old app from v.2 to v.3
3. In order to do this I need of course to open v.3 in Android Studio and manually do all the changes that I've done in my app v.2, it means I have to change the package name, re-skin, and again do the changes that I've done on code on some of the files, so a lot of manual work. This is how I've done it until now.
4. Now I'm interested in using Git but I can't understand if it's possible to have my current app (v.2) in main branch and the new updated source code from dev (v.3) in a dev branch and then compare what changes the dev has added in v.3 in this case dev branch and push to main only the new changes the dev have on v.3 and I keep the rest of files, changes on code on some of the files, re-skin of my v.2 intact.
5. I don't want to use Build Variants or Git Worktree as I don't understand them well.
6. If none of the above works, how are you guys (the one that purchased apps from codecanyon) updating your apps when dev uploads new version on codecanyon.

I hope I was clear what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never tried it but something like this could work.
To be safe make copy of v1 project.

Option 1: Create patch from difference between v1 > v2 and apply to your edited source code.

Open v1 project in android studio and send its code to remote repository with following steps:

1. git init
2. git checkout -b master
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "v1 source"
5. git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>
6. git push -u origin master
7. git tag v1.0

Import v2 code in to local repo with these steps:

1. git checkout -b v2
2. Move to android project pan. copy v2 source code and past it here
   and override everything.
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "v2 source"
5. git push origin v2

Now we have two remote branches with unrelated history lets merge it:

1. git checkout master
2. git merge --allow-unrelated-histories v2
3. Resolve if any conflicts occurs.
4. git commit -m "updated source"
5. git push origin master
6. git tag v2.0
7. create patch from this merge commit from master to keep latest changes. This is what changed from v1 to v2
8. apply this patch file to your old code base

**Option 2** Create patch of your changes and apply it to v2

- Send v1 code to remote repository.
- Make your own changes (changing package name etc.)
- Commit your changes and push it to remote.
- Now copy your changes in to patch using following command
- git format-patch -1 <commit_hash>
- Keep this patch file somewhere safe.
- Any time new version is released apply this patch on top it.
- This is still not bullet proof solution as some manual editing may
  required.

Comment: This sounds like a solution, thank you for your detailed steps. I haven't got any spare time to try it but seems like it work or at least I'm on the right path with some small modifications.